# Is there a way to add a java application to my github website so that my personal website has a live demo of the app?

Tags: java, github

I made a basic github website as a personal website and i want to add some of my work. Is it possible to add a java application/game to my website so that the viewers can test out the game?

What is a github project site?is it any different than the personal website i made?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot execute anything (beside [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions)) on GitHub server side, so all you can do is:

- embed a video illustrating your work
- add pages (like [this one](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sample-code-java)) illustrating how to clone, compile and execute your work.

Regarding the different GitHub pages options, see "[User, Organization, and Project Pages](https://help.github.com/en/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages)"

> Project Pages sites are connected to a specific project, and the site files live on a branch within the project repository.
>
> The source files for Project Pages sites live within the same repository as their project, and they are published from one of the following locations:
>
> - The `master` branch
> - The `gh-pages` branch
> - A folder named "`docs`" located on the master branch

Answer (score 1):

You can embed gif or videi in html. If possible embed the live demo using codepen or codesandbox or you can show list of apps with gif and on click on list item show real demo.

Comment: You can have a look at lab section ofmy website http://hiteshsahu.com/lab . For more inspiration btowse through list of https://github.com/iRaul/awesome-portfolios

Comment: okay thanks, but how did you learn how to embed the codesandbox into your website do you have any resources

Comment: and u have a very nice website, you probably didnt notice this one mistake you spelt learnings wrong on you home page

Comment: Tjanks I will check. You can use iframe like this: https://codesandbox.io/docs/embedding#example-embeds